# How to fix angular material package for core and cdk in version 11.x.x

Tags: angular, angular-material, version-control

I´m trying to package my angular library but I have a difficulty to find the right `@angular/material` version compatible with `@angular/cdk@11.x.x` and `@angular/core@11.x.x` ...

```
npm ERR! Found: @angular/cdk@11.2.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   peer @angular/cdk@"^11.0.1" from @angular-material-components/datetime-picker@5.0.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-material-components/datetime-picker
npm ERR!     peer @angular-material-components/datetime-picker@"~5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/cdk@"10.2.7" from @angular/material@10.2.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!   peer @angular/material@"^10.2.7" from the root project
```

If I do `"@angular/material": "^11.0.0"` as `peerDependencies` , I got this :

```
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^11.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0" from @angular/material@11.2.13
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!     peer @angular/material@"^11.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"12.2.13" from @angular/animations@12.2.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   peer @angular/animations@"^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0" from @angular/material@11.2.13
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!     peer @angular/material@"^11.0.0" from the root project
```

I searched in documentations without success, someone has got the solution ?

Comment: try  "@angular/material": "^10.2.7"

Comment: @frendywijaya, it´s exactly what I did which makes the first errors block.